# launching fish shell to new terminal of tcsh on centos

Tags: centos, xterm, tcsh, fish

I have downloaded fish shell on my centos, but when I switch command to `/bin/fish`

or even try to run `xterm -e /bin/fish`

```
I am getting following error:

Standard input: echo $_ " "; __fish_pwd
                             ^
in command substitution
        called on standard input,

Standard input: __fish_pwd
                ^
in command substitution
        called on standard input,

in command substitution
        called on standard input,

Standard input: echo $_ " "; __fish_pwd
                             ^
in command substitution
        called on standard input,
```

I also tried `xterm -e 'tcsh -i -c fish'` this too gave same error

Comment: How did you install fish?

Comment: since I do not have admin privileges, I have downloaded rpm and extracted it to a location from where i am accessing the fish executable.

Comment: @san Why are you running `/bin/fish` if that's not where you installed fish? Why are you running `xterm -c …` when `xterm` has no such option (it should be `xterm -e fish`)? And how **exactly** did you install fish (what file did you download, which command did you use to extract it, how did you configure fish to look for its files where you put them)? It looks like you did something wrong during the installation, but we can't tell you what if you don't tell us what you did.

Comment: Hi @Gilles , above I mistyped it as `-c`, I did actually used `-e` and I am passing the path where I have saved it in my user/docs folder, so I am passing the path like this `xterm -e /usr/san/documents/bin/fish`, even if the path was wrong I would not have got the above error. As I have already mentioned in my first comment why I cannot install using standard procedure I am passing this path to xterm's command argument which gives the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that fish cannot find its function directory.

The rpm you downloaded has been built with a certain $fish_function_path, and those values aren't valid.

What you'd need to do is adjust those to where you actually placed the files - something like `set fish_function_path ~/.config/fish/functions /etc/fish/functions /usr/san/documents/share/fish/functions`.

(Also I think the error message has improved in newer fish versions)